Rust project is suddenly failing on Windows - slice::from_raw_parts requires the pointer to be aligned and non-null
I think it's something with the SDK because it's the same code that used to run fine. It still runs fine on Linux.
Error:
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at library\core\src\panicking.rs:220:5:
unsafe precondition(s) violated: slice::from_raw_parts requires the pointer to be aligned and non-null, and the total size of the slice not to exceed `isize::MAX`


At an absolute minimum, look at/include a stacktrace to identify what code is (erroneously) calling slice::from_raw_parts.

That error is new, but that means the code was relying on undefined behavior before that the error now guards you from. Is this coming from your code or a library?

Neither. Please see answer below from Mac.

To clarify: you should, no, you must, fix that. Running in release mode fix only the symptoms, not the problem.

@eggyal hey, you are right. In the end, cleaning and rebuilding fixed the issue. It was something to do with the tungstenite crate on Windows. I tried updating it and it worked, downgraded back and made sure to clean/rebuild and still worked, so I think it was some weird bug. I also made sure to downgrade rustc to the stable version (rather than beta)

A recent change to the standard library enabled debug assertions in core/std to fire if the user compiles in debug mode, even if the precompiled standard library is compiled in release mode. See the Asserting unsafe preconditions section of the Rust 1.78.0 release notes.
This is an indication that there was UB in your code or a dependency prior to the change, and it is now being caught because the assertion is only now being compiled in.

Thank you so much. Removing breakpoints works and also running Release. How did you realise that?

What do you mean by UB?

@SpaceMonkey UB is undefined behavior.

For anyone facing this issue in the future. Try to:

Make sure you are on stable rustc not beta.
cargo clean and cargo build
Update tungstenite crate to the latest version. Might need to update reqwest too.

I cannot pinpoint the exact issue but it was one of these steps that fixed it. The code that was failing was in the code to tungstenite::connect function
